# Где хранить пароль

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Пишу приложение asp.net core MVC. Необходимо хранить пароль от почты для SMTP. Для каждого пользователя своя почта и свой пароль. Возник вопрос, где и как безопасно хранить эти данные и строку подключения к бд?

Comment: нигде. как бы вы его не зашифровали в приложении, его можно достать при желании. или на худой конец любым сниффером при подключении увидеть

Comment: @Isaev, ну а если солить?

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk а как это поможет? Соль, емнип, используется для хеширования, а хеширование - это необратимая операция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой свод рекомендаций, который называется [Двенадцать факторов](https://12factor.net/ru/).

Там рекомендуют строки подключения к БД хранить в *переменных окружения*. Этот способ поддерживается в Heroku и Azure, наверное, и в других облачных хостингах тоже.

Альтернатива: использовать скрипт развёртывания, который будет загружать код из репозитория git/mercurial на сервер, а потом будет трансформировать конфигурационные файлы, которые должны храниться в одном из стандартных форматов: XML, JSON, YAML. Этот способ не так безопасен, как первый.

Что касается паролей пользователей от внешних сервисов, их, к сожалению, придётся хранить не в виде хэшей. В целях безопасности код приложения может шифровать пароли перед записью в базу и дешифровывать при чтении.

Это позволит защитить пароли, если злоумышленник получит код приложения и содержимое базы, но не будет знать ключей шифрования, которые будут храниться в переменных окружения.

Этот способ подходит в случае, если у вас множество пользователей в базе, и для каждого надо хранить SMTP/login/password. Если эти пользователи кто-то вроде администраторов или роботов, и их всего 2–3, используйте рекомендации *Двенадцать факторов*.

Comment: ага, то есть эти ключи шифрования должны быть зашиты в скрипте деплоя, верно?

Comment: @tym32167 В том случае, если по каким то причинам нельзя размещать в переменных окружения. Хостинги бывают разные — в массовых и недорогих может быть только FTP-доступ, без возможности настраивать окружение. Тогда да, я бы размести в скрипте деплоя, чтобы код и пароли хранились в разных местах.

Comment: не, я про то, кто и как и когда эти ключи пишет в переменные окружения? Я так понял, это же частью деплоя должно быть?

Comment: @tym32167 Лучше почитать про двенадцать факторов по ссылке. Идея в том, что настройка приложения и деплой делают разные люди, не мешая друг другу. Переменные окружения настраивают и меняют администраторы. Деплой инициируют программисты. В результате, если вдруг надо будет переключиться на резервный сервер БД, админы сделают это самостоятельно, не разворачивая заново приложение. Heroku и Azure содержат средства для ручного редактирования переменных окружения.

Comment: я прочитал и недопонял. Давайте на примере приведу свой вопрос: вот я делаю сервис, он должен подключаться к БД, а значит, хранить строку подключения. Допустим, я хочу, чтобы сервис мог быть маштабирован, то есть человек тянет где то ползунок и хоба - вместо 1 интанса у нас 10. Для такой операции наверное нет смысла дкргать людей, вот и я понять хочу, как бы вы задавали / конфигурировали подобную вещь? Я может глупые вопросы задаю, я с микросервисами давно не работал, но хотел бы понять для себя этот вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 Вот в Azure это как раз так и делается. Там, где у вас App Service, в настройках отдельно у вас есть возможность масштабирования (Scale Up), их меняет администратор. В соседней вкладке есть Application Settings, это переменные окружения, которые будут доступны во всех инстансах, за этим следит инфраструктура Azure. Тут тоже всё делает администратор. Развёртывание приложения делается отдельно, например, в VSTS. VSTS знает только имя App Service, который будет публиковать.

Comment: Ага, то есть принцип похожий на сервер конфигураций - когда все инстансы берут конфиги из единого места. Вроде проясняется, спсибо )

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Core - то родной способ хостинга для вас - Docker / Kubernetes или Azure Web Apps.

Стандартный способ спускания конфигурации и в Azure и в Docker - через переменные окружения.

В случае Kubernetes - есть секреты, которые спускаются в поды через те же переменные окружения.