# Где и как хранить пароль для SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, smtp, пароль

Планирую из программы отправлять Email по определенным событиям.
Все настройки храню через App.config

Как быть с паролем? Хранить тут же, зашифровав?
Если шифровать с ключом, то ключ где хранить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Где хранить пароль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965400/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: Но там про веб, у меня настольное приложение. Я смотрел тот топик

Comment: @tym32167 Способ хороший, у меня такой поддерживается на appharbor. Но вот для non enterprise приложений не факт что подходит, не сайтов тоже. Вот про DPAPI сам топикстартер подкинул неплохую идею, я буду читать про это.

Comment: От туда я понял: можно шифровать пароль, а ключ хранить в переменных окружения.

Comment: @AK ну, это как бы одно другому не мешает :) У меня например не-энтерпрайз, один и тот же проект на 2 хостах - винда и линукс, потому для меня DPAPI вроде не вариант

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю простых способов порешать эту проблему.

До тех пор, пока мы работаем в энтерпрайз-приложениях (читай: есть application сервер) мы всегда может договариваться о том, чтобы хранить пароль в app.config ("всё равно доступ на сервер открыт только тем, кому надо") чуть ли не в явном виде.

Ещё лучше, когда есть домен и мы можем использовать возможность не указывать пароль вообще. Т.е. для SQL соединений мы можем указать `Integrated Security=True` в connection string, для почты мы можем обращаться к корпоративному Exchange Server'у, который знает, что служба запущена от такой-то доменной учётки.

Как только мы уходим в создание приложений, рассчитанных на b2c сегмент, т.е. продаём домашнему пользователю ПО, то вся схема начинает рассыпаться как карточный домик. И вместо почтовика приходится коннектиться к какому-то бесплатному gmail/rambler/mailru/yandex и т.п. сервису, и SQL уже полноценно не подымешь...

Я не знаю, возможно ли вообще общее решение, когда у вас всё для расшифровки находится в одном месте. Вон, даже настройки ODBC винда до сих пор хранит в явном виде в реестре. :(

Единственное что мне приходит в голову: шифровать данные пользователя паролем пользователя (он же нигде не хранится), однако это решение с побочками (забыл пароль - потерял настройки, нельзя зашить пароль в дистрибутив)

Какие-то костыли встречал ([например](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11637348/5752652)), но с такой кучей побочек (только веб-конфиг, только коннекшн стринг и т.п.), что пользоваться неудобно. На дворе шёл уже 2019 год... :(

Comment: Везде пишут про DPAPI, пока вот читаю про него. Не понял про энтропию..достаточно ли мне в методы просто передать стоку с исходным паролем или нет..

Comment: Не использовал, но вроде как [в c# поддержка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=netframework-4.7.2) есть с net 2.0 и даже [примеры](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/security/level5/5_3.php) есть. Было бы интересно послушать отзывы кто пользовался, а то вот я в своих корпоративных приложениях настолько закопался, что даже и не особо в курсе.

Comment: Вот пример, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937095/what-is-the-best-practice-when-saving-passwords-using-the-c-sharp-settings-featu Можно ли просто взять и сделать также? Результат работы функции `EncryptData` хранить в настройках?